# How does this recursion line implemented to print the string reversed?

Tags: c, recursion

Shortly, I need to know how this function works? What's go inside? How is the passed string reversed?

Here is the code and thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void rev (const char* const);

int main()
{
    char str [] = "Hey There";
    rev(str);

    return 0;
}

void rev(const char* const c)
{
    if(c[0]=='\0')
        return ;
    else
    {
        rev( &c[1]);
        putchar(c[0]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** As the commenters advised, I will explain what I'm not understanding more. The string is not reversed, but printed reversely, Ok fine. What is the mechanism used to do this? what is the execution sequence?

Comment: I don't think you will receive many answers if you don't put an effort to explain more in particular what you didn't understand.....

Comment: The string is not reversed, it's merely *printed* in reverse. Big difference.

Comment: The string is not reversed.It is **printed** in reverse.

Comment: Notice that no printing is done until the end of the string has been found, and then ask yourself "what is the printing sequence?"

Comment: @Val_MagicStar I've edited the question, I'm not lazy about asking, It's all about that I just don't know what goes in the code. how it works? how it print the string reversely?

Comment: Work with a shorter string, say 2 characters, draw a little diagram of it, and work it through with pencil and paper.

Comment: @WeatherVane your comment makes sense to me. I think you pointed to something I wasn't able to see, thanks, i will do this

Comment: Next time, copy the full explanation as well as the code:I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the code dictate it to do the rest of the string before processing outputting the current char. Imagine the string "on\0"

```
rev("on\0");
  ->rev("n\0");
    ->rev("\0");  
      <-return;   // hits base case
    putchar('n'); // resumes after recursive call
    <-return;     // invisible return at end of function
  putchar('o');   // resumes after recursive call
  <-return;       // invisible return at end of function
```

Every identation here represents a nested call. Thus at the base case you have 3 calls to `rev` going at the same time, each with different `c`.

Its important to know that `c` is unique for *each invocation* so that when a call to `rev` returns to a previous `rev` `c` has *not changed* in the callee. That makes it nothing special so in fact it works the same way as calling a different function each time that does the same. It resumes after the previous call has returned.

Comment: It's more clear right now, but the only thing i cant understand is how the fumction itterates through the string? what line do move the pointer to the next char?

Comment: That is C pointer magic.. `&c[1]` This gets the address of the second element of `c`. Thus for a *char `"on\n"` with `c` being the memory address 0, `&c[1]` will point to memory address 1 representing `"n\n"`. If the array was integers `&intArr[1]` would be `&intArr+8` (for 64 bits integers)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this recursive function is not reversing the input string. It is just printing it in reversed order.
The logic is simple-
Suppose I am having string str[4] = "ABC" which is null terminated string in C.

- For first call to rev(str) - 
  str[0] is 'A' which is not null --> call rev(str[1]) and print str[0] = 'A'
- For second call to rev()
  str[0] is 'B' which is not null --> call rev(str[1]) and print str[0] = 'B'
- And so on till '\0' is found.

Now before returning from each function call it is printing str[0]-

- So for '\0' - It will simply return without printing anything.
- For 'C', it will print 'C'
- For 'B', it will print 'B'
  And so on.

So the string will be printed in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

As per your program, ** H e y  t h e r e ** ,In rev function,

1. **c[0] = H** is checked as NULL or not  ==> NO
2. Passing address **&c[1] = "ey there"** which starts from **e** to again to rev function.
3. **c[0] = e** is checked as NULL or not  ==> NO
4. Passing address **&c[1] = "y there"** which starts from **y** to again to rev function.
5. this logic continues till end.
6. **c[0] = e** is checked as NULL or not  ==> NO
7. Passing address **&c[1] = \0** which is NULL character to be passed to rev function.
8. once identified **\0**, rev function starts returning.
9. after rev function, we have **putchar(c[0])** which prints latest value of c[0] as 'e' [as per point 6].
10. the print continues **e r e h T  y e H**

Answer (score 0):

To make the action of the function more clear rewrite it the following way

```
void rev( const char * const s )
{
    if ( s[0] != '\0' )
    {
        char c = s[0];
        rev( s + 1 );
        putchar( c );
    }
}
```

So for the first call of the function the function stores the first character of the string in the variable `c`.

Then the function is called the second time moving the pointer to the second character. Again the function stores this character in its own (local) variable `c`.

And so on until the terminating zero is encountered.

Then each function invocation before passing the control to the calling invocation prints its character stored in the variable `c` and you get the reverse order of the characters of the string.

Answer (score -1):

As you have mentioned, it is a recursive function. So the execution goes like this

From main(), rec() is called. The control now enters the rec() function. Where a condition check is made to detect the end of string. Until the end of string is detected, else part gets executed.

Now let us see what happens in else part.

`else` calls `rec()` again. Where the `rec()` is called again until the end of string is met.

so the call sequence goes like this->

```
main()-> rec()->rec(rec(rec(... until \0..) putchar()) putchar())putchar())
```

So on end of the control from last `rec()` function last `putchar()` will be executed. Then on the last before on and goes on till the first `rec()` called from `main()`.

`main()`-> `rec(H)` as it is not null -> it again calls `rec(e)`

Here the control has not came out of the first call to `rec()`. So `rec(H)` looks like

```
rec(H)
{
rec(e);
putchar(H);
}
```

it goes on like this